# Two cloned emulators have the same token, how to change?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing an app and noticed that when using cloned emulator devices with the app, both receive the exact same token id which somehow messes up my notification system.

Now I am wondering what I can actually do against that? Yes I've cloned a device which is very likely to produce the same token but how I can I ensure that two physical devices do not get the same token? At least one scenario I am covering uses two very same devices (same brand, maybe same batch, up to very same patch level, etc) and I would like to get a more robust way of using those tokens.

Edit: I've changed sd card size and some memory values slightly, the token id remains the same

Is this a scenario that can be solved?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you saying that you've observed two physical devices that have the same token?

Answer (score 0):

> *..but how I can I ensure that two physical devices do not get the same token?*

This should never happen on physical devices.

The *cloned emulators* behavior of showing the same token is expected though. There was a similar question before where the dev genereated one emulator image and cloned it up to 20 times I think (can't find the post now though, he was hoping to test multiple tokens sending) and all of them returned the same token.

The tokens are tied to the device. Just changing some of the settings on the emulator won't turn it into a totally different one. Try generating an emulator totally different from the other (image, phone model, android version). I haven't tried it myself yet but I think this could work.